# How to rebuild and lubricate worn plastic parts?

Tags: plastic, tolerance

I'm hoping to rebuild a joystick (sidewinder strategic commander), though the parts inside it are a bit too wobbly because they have been worn beyond tolerances. Due to this wobbling on one (rotation) axis, the sliding action is rough on the x/y plane.

Any recommendation on how and what to use, if there is a compound I can apply to make up for what was lost through friction?

How can I bring the plastic mechanisms back to spec? Also what lubricant is suggested afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any recommendation on how and what to use, if there is a compound I can apply to make up for what was lost through friction?

At first thought, I'm thinking that you scuff the surface of the plastic parts and try to rebuild the missing area with [JB Weld](http://www.jbweld.com/collections/epoxy-adhesives/products/j-b-weld-twin-tube).  After it cures, you can file away the unneeded areas to get the part back to "original" shape.

You'll want as smooth of a contact surface as you can get to reduce wear going forward, so don't forget to sand with increasingly fine grits of sandpaper.  I would probably start at 150 grit and work to at least 600 grit, maybe even 1000 grit.

> Also what lubricant is suggested afterwards?

For lubricant, it really [depends on the type of plastic](http://machinedesign.com/mechanical-drives/lubrication-tips-plastic-gears-and-more) your parts are made of.  The site I linked recommended a thicker synthetic lubricant (silicone-based) or mineral oil.